# A little assistance with my program please (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write an encryption program and I'm in the middle of the assignment. Listed below are the instructions for this part. How can I tell python to redo the while loop if they don't enter e,d,or q? My q entry works fine, but as you can see, I need help trying to create a case where if a user enters another character.

**Ensure that the user enters ‘e’ or ’d’ or ‘q’ by using a while loop to make them redo any bad entry. StartMenu() should then return their choice back to the main() function, where a variable of main() should catch that return value.**

```
 def PrintDescription():
    print 'This program encrypts and descrypts messages using multiple \
encryption methods.\nInput files must be in the same directory as this program.\
\nOutput files will be created in this same directory.'

def StartMenu():
    print 'Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt?'
    print '<e>ncrypt'
    print '<d>ecrypt'
    print '<q>uit'

def main():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.?! \t\n\r"
    PrintDescription()
    while True:
        StartMenu()
        a = raw_input("")
        if a!='e' and a!='d' and a!='q':
          print 'You must enter e, d or q'
          False
          break
        if a == 'q':
         break
```

Comment: `if a not in ('e', 'd', 'q'):`

Comment: `if a!='e' or a!='d' or a!='q':`

Comment: @aug2uag: That will never work.  You probably mean `and`, not `or`.

Comment: Ok that works great. Would you guys happen to know how to make it so that the program does not repeat StartMenu() and PrintDescription again()? I want it to just print Try Again - and subsequently prompt for another input

Comment: :) Thank you, my bad for the unusable code

Comment: @Jodi: Move the `StartMenu()` call outside of the `while True` loop.  ie. before it.

Comment: can you add `False` after `print 'Try Again'`? not 100% that would work, looks it will though

Comment: Thanks Sberry, that worked. - although According to the instructions StartMenu() was supposed to be inside but idk.

Comment: Thanks @Jodi, sorry couldn't be of assistance

Comment: @Aug nevermind - I put it in the right position : ) It worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: @JodiPeterson: I am totally confused as to how adding `False` anywhere except in an assignment would do anything.  It likely isn't doing anything.  Why don't you edit the question with your updated code.

Comment: @Sberry - You're right. It worked once - but after that - I just got an error. Updated the code.

Comment: Yeah, that `False` in there does nothing.  Also, you won't ever get to your second `break` because if `a == 'q'` then the first one will break out of the loop before it gets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of forgoing an extended conversation in comments, this should meet all of your requirements:

```
def main():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.?! \t\n\r"
    PrintDescription()
    a = None
    while a not in ('e', 'd', 'q'):
        if a:
            print "Try again!"
        else:
            StartMenu()
        a = raw_input("")
    if a == 'q':
        sys.exit(0)
```

What's happening...

The first time through the main function, a will be set to None.  A while loop will then start which says to continue running until a is one of the three required letters.  Of course, the first time through a is None, so it will enter the while loop.  Since a is None, `if a:` evaluates to `False`.  So that block will be skipped.  However, the else will be executed and will print the StartMenu.  You will then read the user input and decide what to do when the loop starts over.  If the criteria is met (ie. a is one of the 'e', 'd', or 'q', then it will not iterate the loop again.  However, if a is not in the three letters then another iteration of the loop will begin.  This time, however, a is something so `if a:` evaluates to `True`.  Now it prints "Try again!" and does not print the StartMenu.  From now on this will continue until one of the three letters is entered.

Comment: Thanks for the help sberry. Just trying to study that a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
while raw_input("") not in ['e', 'd', 'q']:
   berate_user()
```

Comment: You may as well grab the 'raw_input' while you have the chance since it is needed in the remainder of the program, and from what I recall is read only / read once.